# WPF Radgridview with ObservableCollection and INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, vb.net, radgridview

Despite the many online tutorials, I still do not quite understand how this is supposed to work.  I have a radgridview where the user can enter an address per row.  I want them to enter the zip code first.  The city and state will be supplied from a database matching the zip code.  So the radgridview must be updated as soon as the zip code is entered.

It appears that using INotifyProperty is the way to go.  I can get the collection to update but cannot get the datagrid to update.

View Model:

```
Public Class ShipTo
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
End Sub

Public Property shipAddressType As String = String.Empty
Public Property orderID As String = String.Empty
Public Property shipName As String = String.Empty
Public Property shipAddr1 As String = String.Empty
Public Property shipAddr2 As String = String.Empty

Private _shipCity As String
Public Property shipCity As String
    Get
        Return _shipCity
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _shipCity = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("shipZip")
    End Set
End Property

Private _shipState As String
Public Property shipState As String
    Get
        Return _shipState
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _shipState = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("shipZip")
    End Set
End Property

Public Property shipZip As String = String.Empty
```

Code to find City and State:

```
                    Dim shipCS As New ShipTo
                    shipCS.shipCity = GetCityAndState.CityLookup(CStr(CType(dgShippingAddresses.SelectedItem, ShipTo).shipZip))
                    shipCS.shipState = GetCityAndState.StateLookup(CStr(CType(dgShippingAddresses.SelectedItem, ShipTo).shipZip))
```

XAML:

Any help appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Since there are no replies, I assume I'm way off base and need to keep digging.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work well.  For anyone else who is struggling here is my solution:

```
    Private _shipSelected As Boolean
Public Property shipSelected As Boolean
    Get
        Return _shipSelected
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        _shipSelected = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("shipSelected")
    End Set
End Property

Public Property shipAddressType As String = String.Empty
Public Property orderID As String = String.Empty
Public Property shipName As String = String.Empty
Public Property shipAddr1 As String = String.Empty
Public Property shipAddr2 As String = String.Empty

Private _shipCity As String
Public Property shipCity As String
    Get
        Return _shipCity
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _shipCity = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("shipCity")
    End Set
End Property

Private _shipState As String
Public Property shipState As String
    Get
        Return _shipState
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _shipState = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("shipState")
    End Set
End Property

Private _shipZip As String
Public Property shipZip As String
    Get
        Return _shipZip
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _shipZip = value
        shipCity = GetCityAndState.CityLookup(_shipZip)
        shipState = GetCityAndState.StateLookup(_shipZip)
        NotifyPropertyChanged("shipZip")
    End Set
End Property
```

Now when the zip is entered in the datagrid, the city and state automatically update.